# Как правильно подключить JQuery в WordPress 5.6?

Tags: php, html, css, jquery, wordpress

В functions.php файлы подключаю вот так

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'konstruktiv_beton_scripts' );
function konstruktiv_beton_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_lib', get_template_directory_uri() . '/vendors/js/jquery.js', array(), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mainscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js' );
}
```

В scripts.js пишу вот так

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(window).load(function($) {
    });
    $(window).resize(function($) {
    });
    $(document).scroll(function($) {
    });
    $(document).ready(function($) {
    });
});
```

Консоль выдает такую ошибку

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at scripts.js?ver=5.6:2
```

Как можно исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: А зачем отключать jquery?

Comment: Потому что мне нужен свой jquery. А WP предлагает свой.

Comment: Подход неправильный. WP 5.6 предлагает свежую версию jQuery 3.4 Вряд ли вам нужен jQuery 3.5, там изменений мало. Значит, downgrade. Вам надо свой jQuery код подтягивать, а не создавать потенциальные проблемы на сайте с кодом jQuery в ядре и плагинах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все таки лучше использовать для своего файла jquery название скрипта по умолчанию, то есть 'jquery' и при подключении своего файла со скриптами которые работают с jquery нужно указывать зависимости, чтобы не получилось что ваш файл подключится до того момента как подключился файл с библиотекой

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'konstruktiv_beton_scripts' );
function konstruktiv_beton_scripts {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/vendors/js/jquery.js', array(), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mainscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js' , ['jquery'] );
}
```

Comment: Теперь консоль это пишет  Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: Попробуйте заменить $ на jQuery.

Comment: var $ = jQuery; - это не помогло

Comment: что будет если вы вставите этот код в ваш скрипт первой строкой $.noConflict();

Comment: Не сработало ((((

Comment: Вывел ответ   -   test

Comment: значит работает)

Comment: Спасибо!!! Заработало!!!

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего использовать jQuery который по умолчанию используетcя в WordPress.
Но если вам принципиально подключить свою версию, то я могу предложить такой код, он является рабочим

```
function footer_enqueue_scripts(){
if(!is_admin()){
    @wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    @wp_register_script('jquery', ("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"), false, false, false);
    @wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

}